# QuickBlox:iOS: Get User list by fullname and tag

Tags: ios, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am developing one Chat application using Quickblox framework. I want to implement search user option. I come across two methods for searching a user. They are search by name and search by tags.

```
//Sridhar
[[[QMApi instance].usersService searchUsersWithTags:tagsValue page:page] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask<NSArray<QBUUser *> *> *task) {
    //

    return nil;
}];


[[[QMApi instance].usersService searchUsersWithFullName:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text page:page] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask<NSArray<QBUUser *> *> *task) {
    //


    return nil;
}];
```

But What I need is , I want to search by name and tags both. Please provide me the best way to do this.

Comment: I need to search like "Select * from users where fullname startswith X and tag = "Y"

Comment: There is a problem with multiple filter server-side by know, please follow Quickblox blog in order to receive updates about fixes here: http://quickblox.com/blog/